# Only seems to be displaying one child when there are supposed to be multiple

Tags: functions, custom-taxonomy, loop, filters, taxonomy

I hope someone can help me, I am trying to get my custom post sub categories to display but can only seem to display one of them. Is there a way I can loop through them all? Im a front end developer and this PHP is messing my brain.
(Dont know how you do it)

The function is below, any help would be great.

```
/**
 * Get taxonomies terms links.
 *
 * @see get_object_taxonomies()
 */
function wpdocs_custom_taxonomies_terms_links() {
    // Get post by post ID.
    $post = get_post( $post->ID );


// Get post type by post.
$post_type = $post->post_type;

// Get post type taxonomies.
$taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( $post_type, 'objects' );

$out = array();

foreach ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy_slug => $taxonomy ){

    // Get the terms related to post.
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy_slug );

    if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {
        $out[] = "<h2>" . $taxonomy->label . "</h2>\n<ul>";
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            $out[] = sprintf( '<li><a href="%1$s">%2$s</a></li>',
                esc_url( get_term_link( $term->slug, $taxonomy_slug ) ),
                esc_html( $term->name )
            );
        }
        $out[] = "\n</ul>\n";
    }
}
return implode( '', $out );
```

}

[image]

The Sub categories that I expect to see are below - Alpha Pizza is the parent and the sub catgories are below.
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve all terms for all taxonomies for the post type, or just those that are assigned to the particular post be viewed?

Comment: Can you add to your question a list of what you expect to see as well?

Comment: I have amended to question to show which categories im looking for.that arent appearing.

Comment: @Dan im only looking to display the sub categories / posts of the current parent... in this case Alpha Pizza

Comment: I see. So the the new image in your question is showing a 'top-level' category, rather than a `page`?

Comment: Thats correct Dan

Comment: Ok. In this case, `$post` cannot be used here, as taxonomy terms are not `posts` and do not have `post_id`. What's the name of the file that has the code in it in question?

Comment: it is within the functions PHP and is called in the category-ranges-template. This is a custom built site in wordpress and these are custom posts i believe. the post type= recipes im not sure if this can be done.. ill keep looking

Comment: Ok, but I can tell you that the code in your question is a function for fetching a post's terms, rather than getting child terms of another term. The above function serves no purpose in a categories/terms/taxonomy template. I recommend trying replacing the above function with that in my answer, and then call that new function in `category-ranges-template.php`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to show the terms of just one taxonomy at a time, then this will produce what you're looking for:

```
function my_theme_get_child_terms(){

    $return = '';
    $current_term = get_queried_object()->term_id;
    $term_info = get_term($current_term);
    $sub_categories = get_term_children( $current_term, $term_info->taxonomy );

    $return .= '<h2>' . $term_info->taxonomy . '</h2><ul>';
    foreach ( $sub_categories as $cat ) {
        $term = get_term_by( 'id', $cat, $term_info->taxonomy );
         $return .= sprintf( '<li><a href="%1$s">%2$s</a></li>',
            esc_url( get_term_link( $cat, $term_info->taxonomy ) ),
            esc_html( $term->name )
    }
    $return .= '</ul>';

    return $return;
}
```

You need to put the above code inside a relevant `template file`. E.g. `taxonomy.php` or `index.php`.

Comment: Thanks for this Im not sure I understand where to put it? do i need to wrap it in something?    i need to show all of the sub categories for each parent not just one... sorry if i confused you, thanks for your help

Comment: Edited just now to make it a bit easier. Put the above function into your theme's functions.php (replacing 'my_theme' with your theme's slug) and then in 'category-ranges-template.php', replace `'wpdocs_custom_taxonomies_terms_links()'` with `'my_theme_get_child_terms()'`